# How to solve HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error 0x8007000d in IIS 10.0 for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, iis

I am using IIS 10.0 to host my Laravel Website. I already have laravel code containing web.config file in public folder. However after hosting the site, I am getting HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error with Error Code  0x8007000d. I checked the syntax of XML format in web.config and it seems to be ok. I also cheked permission for my public folder, which I have given all access to all user groups.

Here below is my web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Error 500.19 on IIS7 "Malformed XML" in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132029/http-error-500-19-on-iis7-malformed-xml-in-web-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 0x8007000d means **URL rewriting module** (referenced in web.config) is missing or proper version is not installed.

Just install URL rewriting module via web platform installer.

I recommend to check all dependencies from web.config and install them.

Comment: Can you please tell me what all dependencies needed for web.config of laravel project?

Comment: Just do composer install to install everything again, did you tied to reinstall your URL rewriting module ?

Comment: I haven't installed URL Rewrite module via Web Platform Installer. Now I did and it worked for me. Thank you so much Jonathan

Comment: Glad to help you !