# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error (0x8007000d)

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, iis-10, asp.net5

I am trying to deploy a .Net Core 5 WASM app to a brand new Windows Server 2019 virtual server and am encountering the very generic `The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.` error message as part of it.

Via Add/Remove programs, I've confirmed I have .Net Core 5.02 Windows Server Hosting, Runtime (x64 and x86) and the 5.0.102 x64 SDK installed. I've read this could be a permissions thing, so I granted Everyone Full Control on all files where the site is at (obviously temporary!) and confirmed within IIS that the .Net Core module is installed.

When I try to edit the configuration file through IIS, I get this prompt, so I know it's mad about something with the web.config, but for the life of me can't figure out what.

[image]

The full web.config file (which was generated from publishing via VS [where the app works fine] to a local folder, then copying it up to the web server) looks pretty basic to me. Any ideas? Everything I've searched for on here says either permissions or something about a misconfigured web.config, but nothing obvious stands out. Here's the full config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Error 500.19 with 0x8007000d on IIS7 "Malformed XML" in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132029/http-error-500-19-with-0x8007000d-on-iis7-malformed-xml-in-web-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I finally figured it out! The `<rewrite />` section is what it was mad about and I had to install the [URL Rewrite Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) from Microsoft to get it to work. It would've been significantly faster if, instead of just "I can't read this", the error message provided said something like "unknown section `<rewrite />`, but at least it's working now.

Hopefully this little tidbit helps anyone else standing up a new web server!

Comment: No need. This has been well known for more than a decade.