# HTTP Error 500.19 config file path does not exist

Tags: wcf, iis

Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Detailed Error Information
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x80070003
Config Error    Cannot read configuration file
Config File \?\D:\Company\ABC\web.config
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/services/application/cardmanagement
Physical Path   D:\ABC\DEF\Website.Hosts
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User  Not yet determined
Config Source
   -1: 
    0:

I am getting this strange error when I try to browse the service. Problem is Physical path is correct but **config path** is even does not exist in my machine where all applications and iis installed. So I am surprised from where its taking that path and how to correct it.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597929/iis-7-5-http-500-19-internal-server-error-config-invalid