# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

newbie here,
I am having an error in all of my projects and backups when executing my project visual studio 2012. Last week it was working fine and then the error came out. I am just using localhost.

these are solutions that i found and it still didn't work: 
:(

-In IIS Manager - Feature Delegation set HandlerMapping to Read/Write.

-Control Panel, Turn windows features on or off, Internet Information Services, World Wide Web Services, enable Application Development Features except CGI.

-I gave IIS_IUSRS full control to my project folder.

Any other suggestions?

error message

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module    IIS Web Core
>
> Notification    BeginRequest
>
> Handler    Not yet determined
>
> Error Code    0x80070003
>
> Config Error    Cannot read configuration file
>
> Config File    \?\C: -- web.config
>
> Requested URL    http://localhost:49926/Home.aspx
>
> Physical Path --
>
> Logon Method    Not yet determined
>
> Logon User    Not yet determined
>
> Request Tracing Directory
>   C:\Users\john\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\ --
>
> Config Source:    -1: 
>       0:

my [Web.config] file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <pages>
        <controls>
           <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" /></controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>  

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionString" connectionString="DELETED" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: What webserver you are using? What webpage are you trying to fetch?
Have you changed configuration lately? If you have I suggest you go over your changes since 500 generally indicates a server error. Have you added any changes to your backend application? If you provide more info it may be easier for people to help you.

Comment: webserver IIS 8 as localhost. Just trying to go to startpage(home.aspx) after executing in visual studio and the error come out. I really didnt change any code in backend. I guess it start when I pulled from bitbucket respository the project then when i tried to execute the 500.19 came out, i am not really 100% sure this is related.  but then our project does work on a different PC. only on my pc shows the 500.19 error. Please do tell me if you need other information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web Application Problems (web.config errors) HTTP 500.19 with IIS7.5 and ASP.NET v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808680/web-application-problems-web-config-errors-http-500-19-with-iis7-5-and-asp-net)

Answer (score 2):

according to me there should be problem in your application pool.. Just change and select proper **`version 4.5`** pool to solve your server problem.. If still not work for you then inform..