# IIS Error :- HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, localhost, iis-7.5

i'm hosting my asp.net project on IIS i configured all the settings in web.config file, while i'm running it on localhost it giving me following error:

```
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web Application Problems (web.config errors) HTTP 500.19 with IIS7.5 and ASP.NET v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808680/web-application-problems-web-config-errors-http-500-19-with-iis7-5-and-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below mentioned solutions
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942055

Comment: Could you expand on what those solutions are in your answer please? As it stands your answer is a link only answer and is likely to be downvoted or deleted as [link only answers are considered bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942055 i followed this but i couldn't find solution