# Can't run a .Net 4.5.2 web app in IIS 7.5 anymore on my dev machine

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis-7.5

**Short story**:
I have an asp.net MVC app running on .net 4.5.2 that I can't run anymore. Error message in browser is:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.
>   Error Code    0x8007000d

Context:
Windows 7 Ultimate SP1
VS2015

**Long story**:
My working day got into a nightmare after Visual Studio stopped behaving correctly. I remember that I installed a few things (like the latest azure sdk or the azure powershell for example, but I think it's not related) and at some point, I got a strange popup in the sys tray saying something like "user privileges had been changed". There was nothing I could do and it asked to restart. It looked like a microsoft security essentials window...

Then I got an error in VS:

> error  : The Web Application Project Know.WebSite is configured to use
>   IIS.  Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient
>   privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine.

I tried to fix it with [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859891/error-unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase) and it worked.

But then I was not able to debug anymore, with this error:

> vs2015 unable to start debugging on the web server iis does not list a
>   web site

I decided to reinstall IIS first. It was not a good idea because it broke .Net in IIS and my web app could not run (the error message I mention at the top). So I ran aspnet_regiis -i but nothing changed. OK! I uninstalled all dotnet versions >= 4, ran the microsoft cleaning tools, reinstalled IIS, then each and every .Net versions and ran also a VS2015 repair. Guess what? Nothing changed. So I'm completely lost.

I don't know if you have some ideas but I don't. I'm stuck and can't develop my app anymore. I'm near reinstalling Windows and every piece of app I have which will take 2 or 3 days!!

Is there a way to repair an IIS install?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808680/web-application-problems-web-config-errors-http-500-19-with-iis7-5-and-asp-net).

It appears that reinstalling IIS while Url Rewrite was installed needed also a reinstall of this module.

Microsoft attn: mind changing/adapting your error message?