# IIS 10 500.19 error

Tags: asp.net, web, iis-express, iis-10

Currently running IIS 10 and after bringing down a new project (TFS) I cannot get the site to run due to a 500.19 error. To me it looks like IIS is looking for the web.config file in the wrong location (pointing to a directory on the project creators PC) and I don't know how to change this to point to the one on my machine. Anyone had this problem before and knows of a solution?

Edit: the error code I get is 0x80070003

Comment: Check this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808680/web-application-problems-web-config-errors-http-500-19-with-iis7-5-and-asp-net

Comment: I've seen that article and it didn't help me; different error code to me I have edited the post to include it. IIS simply isn't looking in the right location but I don't know how to change it