# Tool to validate a web.config

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-10

Is there a tool that I can use to validate my web.config? The reason I ask is that the file appears to be valid XML and IIS is complaining that file is invalid. No explanation or indication as to why.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error
Config File    \?\C:\DignityFiles\Source\simplicity\Simplicity\web.config
Requested URL      http://simplicity-local.dignitytest.co.uk:80/
Physical Path
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
Config Source:

-1: 
    0:

More Information:
This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.

View more information » [This takes you to "https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/942055/-http-error-500-19-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage"]

[image: Screen shot of the IIS Error]

[image: Screen shot of the support page]

[Link to the web.config (**Note:** sensitive information has been redacted)](https://u40127865.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40127865/Web.config)

Comment: Can you please add error, which you can see in IIS

Comment: For future visitors of this page, there's the [Web.config Validator](https://elmah.io/tools/config-validator/).

Answer (score 9):

I have (eventually) found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41267673

Installing the URL rewrite module fixed my issue.

Comment: This didn't answer the question, but fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

This answer addressses the immediate concern, but if you are looking for a general solution in powershell I have created a function that addresses this.

The full answer is here: [how do i validate an IIS web.config in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68260818/how-do-i-validate-an-iis-web-config-in-powershell/68260819#68260819)

But the gist of it is you have to find all the "filters" and test each of them individually via Get-WebConfiguration