# Something wrong with my web.config file while hosting web service

Tags: rest, iis, deployment

To give some context: 
I'm trying to deploy a webservice I built, within visual studio you have the option to use 'Folder Deployment', I am using this option and that deployment allows me to make a build within a folder that has an executable which works like a charm when I'm using it on localhost but because my webservice needs to be used through a network, I need to deploy it to IIS which gives me some challenges.

I'm trying to host my RESTful API web service on the IIS server as explained in this article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/publishing-asp-net-web-api-rest-service-using-file-system-method/  but every time I add it to the server, and try surfing to the site I get the following error page: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error --> 0x8007000d which apparantly tells me that something is wrong with my web.config file but I never touched that during my development..... perhaps you guys see something odd as here is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Flame_webservice.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 21d59c04-6877-4549-9ff7-c37f07155f97-->
```

After searching for solutions I already found several articles that suggested installing things but it doesn't seem to do the trick for me, the following article I have tried:
[Web Application Problems (web.config errors) HTTP 500.19 with IIS7.5 and ASP.NET v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808680/web-application-problems-web-config-errors-http-500-19-with-iis7-5-and-asp-net)

I don't think I'm using AJAX but maybe I am so I haven't tried that yet.

My webservice contains 3 controllers which are essentially websites but I don't see an explicit route to the websites in the web.config file, I'm not sure if that can cause issues?

I will continue searching but it's becoming a pretty rough ride at the moment due to my limited experience with hosting web services. Or am I perhaps using IIS while I shouldn't? I mean I've tried turning off my firewall and reaching the executable running on localhost through my IP address but it doesn't seem to work which led me to believe I needed a server to reach the running web service on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue and what helped was:
installing **.net core windows hosting** on the server.

Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting -Version 3.1.10